# Ionic 5 - HTML view

Tags: ipad, ionic5

We are building hybrid app using ionic 5, one of the requirement is to open the HTML files downloaded to the local app content folder. The HTML files has reference to js & css files. The difficulty we face is the HTML file opens successfully and the javascript & CSS reerred is not opening. we tried using inappbrowser, window.open, previewanyfule plugin most of them same result. need guidance in opening such files.

Comment: Any guidance will help us

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to run your ionic app on an android or iOS device you will need Cordova or capacitor.